# How to change MessageContext.ResponseAddress in consume method

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

I have a situation when my RabbitMQ server available from local network and from the internet also, and if I got a request from the local network the rabbitmqUri looks like

> rabbitmq://172.16.0.1 ...

but if I want to get an access to this server from the internet my rabbitmq uri looks like

> rabbitmq://245.123.155.81 ...

So the problem occurs when I am getting the request from the internet and my concumer is trying to response (context.RespondAsync) to the external ip insted of inernal.

---

The question is:
**Is it possible to change the context.ResponseAddress to a local ip addres (this propery is private, readonly)?**

Comment: What do you use as RabbitMq URI for endpoint configuration?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify your question, my configuration based on this example: http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/usage/request_response.html

Comment: The docs are here http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/transports.html
In the line `cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://a-machine-name/a-virtual-host"), host =>`, what is the uri?

Comment: rabbitmq://172.16.0.1/some_virtual_host/

Answer (score 1):

There is a constructor for `MessageRequestClient` that takes explicit response address:

```
public MessageRequestClient(ISendEndpointProvider sendEndpointProvider, 
     IRequestPipeConnector connector, 
     Uri responseAddress, 
     Uri serviceAddress,
     TimeSpan timeout, 
     TimeSpan? timeToLive = default(TimeSpan?), 
     Action<SendContext<TRequest>> callback = null)
```

From what you have now, you need to change the initialisation to:

```
var client = 
     new MessageRequestClient<MyRequest, MyResponse>(bus, bus, 
          new Uri("rabbitmq://245.123.155.81/some_virtual_host"),
          serviceAddress, requestTimeout);
```